# Converting javascript Replace to C# Replace

Tags: javascript, c#

Can anyone help me in converting this javascript code into c#

```
   modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[0]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "@$1" ) ;
    modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[1]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "A$1" ) ;
    modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[2]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "B$1" ) ;
    modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[3]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "C$1" ) ;
    modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[4]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "D$1" ) ;
    modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[5]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "E$1" ) ;
    modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[6]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "F$1" ) ;
    modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[7]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "G$1" ) ;
    modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[8]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "H$1" ) ;
    modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[9]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "I$1" ) ;
    modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[●]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "J$1" ) ;
    modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[“]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "T$1" ) ;
    modified_substring = modified_substring.replace ( /[”]([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])/g , "U$1" ) ;
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. [Show what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and ask a specific question regarding where you're having trouble. As it stands, this question is too broad because you're just asking others to write your code for you.

Comment: I am trying to convert my this javascript code into backend i.e. c#.net so i what I want is how can i get the functionality like the above one this code is working fine.

Comment: Yes, that was abundantly clear from your question. The problem is that you haven't attempted anything or asked a specific answerable question. Your question isn't a question, it's "write some C# code for me". Please review [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out C# Regex Replace. Here is a good starting point:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to do it all inline, as done with the JavaScript code, you could do something like this: 
modified_substring = Regex.Replace(modified_substring, pattern, replacement);

Don't forget the using directive for System.Text.RegularExpressions.

Comment: It would be great help if you can give me pattern for this example thanks in advance